# The Local Testing connection could not be configured

Tags: browserstack

I can’t run local testing(for example http://localhost:3000) on browserstack.
I'm using Linux Mint 18.3 Sylvia x64. Browser is Chromium.
The browser’s extension (app) is installed.

The screenshot shows that there is no connection.
http://joxi.ru/Y2LJBv0H9MBv8r

The checkbox is checked.
http://joxi.ru/1A5PvVpCnzMww2

I tried this manual https://www.browserstack.com/local-testing.

```
./BrowserStackLocal --key
```

The above command is started, but nothing happened.

BrowserStack's Support Answer:
Thank you for joining the screen share session. As per our investigation, it seems that few of the IP's of our servers hosted on AWS are blocked due to Telegram blockage by Roskomnadzor which is leading towards the issue. 
Having said that, our team is evaluating alternate solutions for our Russian users and I will be sure to notify you of the developments.

Cool!
But my neighbour doesn't have problems, he has Windows. 
We have a common Internet provider.

Comment: From what I know, you should be using a stable version of chrome or firefox when testing on browserstack for best results

Comment: @KireetiAannamaraj I tried opera chrome ff

Answer (score -1):

Try replacing 'localhost' in the URL you are using with the IP address of the machine. For example, if you are testing the URL "http://localhost:3000/index.html" try using `http://<machine_ip_address>:3000/index.html` instead.

Comment: Some web applications will require you to specify a hostname because else they won't react to any request.